# In Recharts, how do I show just the first and final tick on an axis?

Tags: recharts

I have a Recharts LineChart with 14 data points (although in future this may vary, so ideally I'd like to not have to hardcode that).  I want to show 2 tick values on the XAxis - the first and last.

So, I have:

```js
<LineChart width={100} height={50} data={lineData}>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="data" dot={false} />
  <XAxis />
</LineChart>
```

where lineData is:

```js
"lineData": [
  { "data": 43.0 },
  { "data": 44.5 },
  { "data": 45.0 },
  { "data": 41.0 },
  { "data": 35.0 },
  { "data": 32.0 },
  { "data": 24.0 },
  { "data": 18.0 },
  { "data": 21.0 },
  { "data": 26.0 },
  { "data": 32.0 },
  { "data": 46.0 },
  { "data": 44.0 },
  { "data": 42.0 }
]
```

I've tried various combinations of interval, tickCount and a ticks array, but nothing has worked - eg the code above gives "1 3 6 9 13".

How do I show only the first and final ticks on the XAxis? They can be hardcoded, so let's say I want "12:00" at the start and "16:00" at the end.  How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show the first and last ticks on an axis, you can use the `ticks` props that takes an array with specific ticks to show. In this array, you could simply put the first, and last tick values.

If you need a specific label on the tick, you could add a property on the array, say `name` with the hard-coded name you wish to use, like this:

```js
const lineData = [
  { "data": 43.0, "name": "12:00" },
  { "data": 44.5 },
  ...
  { "data": 44.0 },
  { "data": 42.0, "name": "16:00" }
];
```

And then, in the `XAxis`, specify the ticks to show:

```js
<LineChart width={200} height={50} data={lineData}>
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="data" dot={false} />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" ticks={['12:00', '16:00']} />
  <YAxis />
</LineChart>
```

Otherwise, if you do not wish a hard-coded label, you'll need to provide the `0` value and the `lineData.length - 1` (13 in your example) value to set the first & last ticks.

Here is a fiddle to see the result with the hard-coded values: https://jsfiddle.net/hvgxw5pc/1/

Comment: Thank you, that's really clear.  Tried it and it works!

Comment: worth setting `interval="preserveStartEnd"` to the `XAxis` if you're not showing the `YAxis`